# ssh to a server not on the same domain

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ssh

I have a linux server running Ubuntu 16.04. I installed the ssh-server on it and have it running with the `sudo ssh service start` and can see it with `ps aux | grep ssh`. I want to ssh into it from my laptop (also running Ubuntu 16.04). They are both connected to the same Wifi. When I ssh from my laptop to the server using `ssh username@serverIP`, I get

`ssh: connect to host <serverIP> port 22: Connection timed out`

Since some of the recommendations here was to use another port number and not 22, I changed the port to 2220 in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on the server. I then ssh from my laptop using `ssh username@serverIP -p 2220` and I get the same connection refused error.

Next I went and manually changed the IP address and netmask of one of the interfaces on the server using `ifconfig eth0 <laptopIP + 1> netmask <laptop_subnet>` so that it falls under the same subnet as my laptop is. I then tried to ssh using `ssh ssh username@LaptopIP+1 -p 2220` and I get

`ssh: connect to host <laptopIp+1> port 2220: Connection refused`

Am I over complicating this? How do I get a connection to this server?

Comment: "Connection timed out" "I get the same connection refused error" _Connection timed out_ and _Connection refused_ are different errors with different causes. You should be clear and specific about which error you're getting at different times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely the firewall blocking the connection. You should have a look to see what your firewall policies are with the `sudo ufw status` command. You may get output that looks similar to this(but likely fewer ports open):

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

25,53,80,110,443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
53,67,68/udp               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
51413/tcp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
51413/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
6969/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
25,53,80,110,443/tcp (v6)  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
53,67,68/udp (v6)          ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
51413/tcp (v6)             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
51413/udp (v6)             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
6969/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

This will especially be true if you change your port to something other than the default 22. You can allow connections on a specific port by using that same command:

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

or if you want to stick with the alternative port, modify the above command to allow 2220(changing the default port is of course recommended if this is a production or "public" server). Once you've allowed the port, check the status of ufw again to be sure, then try connecting remotely via ssh.

See also: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands

Answer (score 0):

Check the server firewall, you might need to create rules to allow connections to specific ports.

Here is one reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9206/is-there-a-preinstalled-or-automatic-firewall